# Power BI - Calculated column for occurrences over 50%

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

Anyone help?

Just two directly related tables, Purchase Header & Purchase Line with direct relationship between the two based on two common columns (Delivery No).

I want to calculate the number of lines where the delivery is greater than 50%. So the Header has the Delivery No, and the Line table has the Delivery No split out across either a single or multiple line. If there are 7 deliveries that are counted as Day 1 (value in Delivery Day column in Line Table), and 4 are on Day 1 and 3 are on Day 2, then return me the value 'Day 1'. If there is just one Delivery and it's Day 2, then return Day 2...essentially, anything that's > 50%.

I feel that this should be achieveable, but it's stumped two of us in our team and I've been looking at it far too long!

Have tried numerous things to get this working but to be honest, nothing has worked at all. Completely stumped on it

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have the chance "to look at it" since you don't share any sample data in copyable format.

Comment: Hi there. Apologies, first time posting here. Some sample data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jYb0CftenoURkr-Oeay2102xtiOyfbdU/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=108389835693298469342&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: What are you after? A measure that should work in a given evaluation context, or just a calculated column in your detail table?

Comment: Ideally I was looking for a column for this.